# How can I get the current timestamp minus 30 minutes in nushell?

Tags: nushell

I searched for a replacement of `date -d` in Nushell but I didn't find anything.
How can I get the current datetime minus N minutes ? Like this `$((date now) - 30 minutes)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subtract a duration (like `30min`) from the current date provided by `date now` (you can also add a negative duration with the same effect):

```bash
(date now) - 30min
# or
(date now) + -30min
```

So, if your input is an integer representing the amount of minutes, just append `"min"` to it as a string, then use `into duration` to convert it before subtracting/adding like above:

```bash
30 | (date now) - ($"($in)min" | into duration)
# or
-30 | (date now) + ($"($in)min" | into duration)
```

---

For the sake of completeness, although not recommended, you could also go down the full arithmetic route by formatting the current date as UNIX timestamp measured in seconds using `format date "%s"`, then subtracting/adding the amount of minutes also converted into seconds (i.e. multiplied by sixty), and converting that further into nanoseconds (i.e multiplying again by 1 billion) because that's what `into datetime` accepts as numerical input. Use it with the `--timezone LOCAL` (or `-z l`) option to re-include your local time zone (which got lost with the UNIX timestamp).

```bash
30 | (((date now | format date "%s") | into int) - $in * 60) * 1_000_000_000 | into datetime -z l
# or
-30 | (((date now | format date "%s") | into int) + $in * 60) * 1_000_000_000 | into datetime -z l
```

For super precision, you could even extract the UNIX timestamp directly in nanoseconds using `%s%f` as the format string, then subtract/add the amount of minutes also converted into nanoseconds:

```bash
30 | ((date now | format date "%s%f") | into int) - $in * 60_000_000_000 | into datetime -z l
# or
-30 | ((date now | format date "%s%f") | into int) + $in * 60_000_000_000 | into datetime -z l
```

Comment: Alternatively: `(date now) - (30min) `

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't expect it was so simple!